# Transit visa for US permanent resident travelling thru Toronto

Tags: indian-citizens, canada, transit-visas, us-residents

I am permanent resident of US with Indian citizenship, plan travelling from US to India and back by Air Canada: do i need transit visa and how do i apply for it. Not leaving Airport at Toronto

Answer (score 8):

Permanent residents of the United States do not require a visa to visit or transit through Canada.  You no longer require [eTA](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/entry-requirements-country.html#lawful-pr-us):

> As of April 26, 2022, lawful permanent residents of the United States must show these documents for all methods of travel to Canada:
>
> - a valid passport from their country of nationality (or an equivalent acceptable travel document) and
> - a valid green card (or equivalent valid proof of status in the United States)

Also see [I am a lawful permanent resident of the U.S. (green card holder) and my home country will not issue a passport to me. Can I apply for an eTA using a document other than a passport?](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1117&top=16):

> As of April 26, 2022, lawful permanent residents of the United States are exempt from the eTA requirement.

Answer (score 2):

As  US permanent resident you do not need a visa to visit Canada,  and if you do not need a visa to visit Canada you do not need a visa to transit through Canada.

Comment: Which is correct? Don't need anything, or need an eTA?

Comment: You do not need a visa. You do need an ETA. An ETA is not a visa.

Comment: "As of April 26, 2022, lawful permanent residents of the United States are exempt from the eTA requirement."